# jquery.datatables.editable - highlight selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm new to JS. How can i highlight selected row when user clicked on it at editable datatable?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more information than that.  Do you have any html code you can show?  What happens right now when the user clicks on the row?

Comment: I have HTML <table>. And i have JS code for make it datatable and editable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jquery datatable plugin, there is an example here :
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_row.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Add/remove class to a row when clicked on */
    $('#example tr').click( function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
    } );

    /* Init the table */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( );
} );

/*
 * I don't actually use this here, but it is provided as it might be useful and demonstrates
 * getting the TR nodes from DataTables
 */
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    return oTableLocal.$('tr.row_selected');
}
```